# "making anonymous inner class a lambda" sonar suggestion

Tags: java

Im having trouble in understanding the way lambda works or how to implement the suggestion,

I have this code

```
JsonSerializer<Date> ser = new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
                @Override
                public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                    return src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());
                }
            };
```

And I tried to follow the suggestion like so:

```
JsonDesializer<Date> ser = (Date src, Type typeOfSrc,
                JsonSerializationContext context) -> src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());
```

But that doesn't compile, can someone help me a bit? thanks :)

Comment: Don't include the types: `(src, typeOfSrc, context) -> src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());`. The types are already clear from the `serialize` parameters.

Comment: What is the JDK you use for compilation? (if you don't know, enter `javac -version` in the terminal of your choice)

Comment: @Tom I delete the types but it still says that "the target of this expression must be a funcitonal interface"

Comment: @qutax it prints javac 1.8.0_131

Comment: Because you've changed `JsonSerializer<Date> ser` to `JsonDesializer<Date> ser`. Why? That class doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Tom true <3 my mistake lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

`JsonDesializer` -> `JsonSerializer`

This compiles:

```java
JsonSerializer<Date> ser
            = (Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) -> src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());
```